# Using Recursion to add to a trie

Tags: python-3.x, autocomplete, trie

I have been learning about the Trie structure through python. What is a little bit different about his trie compared to other tries is the fact that we are trying to implement a counter into every node of the trie in order to do an autocomplete (that is the final hope for the project). So far, I decided that having a recursive function to put the letter into a list of dictionaries would be a good idea.

Final Product (Trie):

```
Trie = {"value":"*start"
        "count":1
        "children":["value":"t"
                    "count":1
                    "children":["value":"e"
                                "count":1
                                "children":[...]
```

I know that a recursion would be very useful as it is just adding letters to the list, however, I can't figure out how to construct the basic function and how to tell the computer to refer to the last part of the dictionary without writing out

```
Trie["children"]["children"]["children"]["children"]
```

a bunch of times. Can you guys please give me some ideas as of how to construct the function?

--Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you only want to store a counter in the end-of-word node. (I always use a separate node for this!). So given a prefix, you work your way down the Trie, then perform a traversal to find the end-of-word nodes below your prefix, pushing them into a binary tree by their counter value. Once you have all the end-of-word nodes, you perform a post-order traversal to collect the end-of-word nodes with the largest counters - however many you decide. With each of these collected end-of-word nodes, you can obtain a list of candidate words most likely to fit the prefix! From just the end-of-word node, and storing the parent node in each node, you zoom up to the root to re-assemble the word!

Answer (score 0):

### The Trie itself containing the root node and insert/find functions

```
class Trie:
    def __init__(self):
         ## Initialize this Trie (add a root node)
         self.root = TrieNode()

    def insert(self, word):
         ## Add a word to the Trie
         current_node = self.root
        for char in word:
            if char not in current_node.children:
                 current_node.insert(char)
            current_node = current_node.children[char]
        current_node.is_word = True
    
    def find(self, prefix):
        ## Find the Trie node that represents this prefix
        current_node = self.root
        for char in prefix:
             if char not in current_node.children:
                 return None
             current_node = current_node.children[char]
             return current_node
```

This is a class method to implement autocomplete with trie.

```
class TrieNode:
    def __init__(self):
        ## Initialize this node in the Trie
        self.is_word = False
        self.children = {}
        self.results = []

    def insert(self, char):
         ## Add a child node in this Trie
         self.children[char] = TrieNode()
    
    def suffixes(self, suffix=''):
        ## Recursive function that collects the suffix for 
        ## all complete words below this point
        for char, node in self.children.items():
            if node.is_word:
                 self.results.append(suffix + char)
            if node.children:
                  self.results += node.suffixes(suffix + char)
        results = self.results.copy()
        self.results = []
        return list(set(results))
```

Solutions can be obtained by using the following command.

```
MyTrie = Trie()
wordList = ["ant", "anthology", "antagonist", "antonym", 
    "fun", "function", "factory", "trie", "trigger", "trigonometry", "tripod"]
for word in wordList:
    MyTrie.insert(word)

MyTrie.find('a').suffixes()
MyTrie.find('f').suffixes()
MyTrie.find('t').suffixes()
MyTrie.find('tri').suffixes()
MyTrie.find('anto').suffixes()
```